# xlsread can't find an existing file - matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io, xls

I am using windows XP, matlab 2010b 
I have encountered a very wierd problem: when trying to read an excel file using:

> > xlsread('c:/s.xls')

I am geeting:

> > XLSREAD unable to open file c:\s.
> >     File c:\s.xls not found.

the file is there I chacked 100 times...any ideas?
thank you
ariel

Comment: Is it an xls file or an xlsx file from the newer forms of Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
[fname,fpath] = uigetfile({'*.xls';'*.xlsx'});
if fpath==0, error('no file selected'); end

[num,txt,raw] = xlsread( fullfile(fpath,fname) );
```

The file can be located anywhere on your hard-disk...

Answer (score -3):

2 points:

1. MATLAB only searches for files in the specified search paths.
2. xlsread only takes in the filename as input, not the path.

You may consider:

1. moving the file to your MATLAB current directory, or
2. including C:\ in the list of search paths. You can do that by going to File> Set Path> Add Folder.

Then give the command as:

```
[num, txt] = xlsread(‘s.xls’);
```

Or even

```
[num, txt] = xlsread(‘s’);
```

if it is a .xls file (instead of .xlsx or some other extension). xlsread searches for .xls files by default.

Also note that you need variables num and txt to store the data read from the file. If your file contains only double values (no text), you may leave out the txt variable.

Refer to http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xlsread.html for more details.